# Regex to find subelement in XML

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I am using the Regular Expression search feature in Notepad++ to find matches in a few hundred files.

My goal is to find a parent/child combo in in each. I don't care a lot about what specifically is selected (parent and child or just child). I just want to know if the parent contains a specific child.

I want to find a parent  element that also has a child  element.

Example of what it should find (since one of the sub-elements is a ):

```
<description>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
    <something>
    </something>
    <description>
    </description>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
</description>
```

Example of what it should NOT find:

```
<description>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
    <something>
    </something>
    <notadescription>
    </notadescription>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
<description>
```

Each may have other children and sub children as well. They both also may be in the same document.

If I search for this:

```
<description>(.*)<description>(.*)</description>
```

It selects too much, because it will select another top level  when I only want it to select the child for that 2nd piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're working with Notepad++, here here a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<description>(?:(?!</description).)*<description>(?:(?!<description>).)*</description>`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Explanation:**

```
<description>               # opening tag
(?:(?!</description).)*     # tempered greedy token, make sure we have not closing tag before:
<description>               # opening tag
(?:(?!<description>).)*     # tempered greedy token, make sure we have not opening tag before:
</description>              # closing tag
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `(.*)` it is greedy
here is an example why you shouldn't use it in you case

```
<description>
    <otherstuff>
    </otherstuff>
    <description>
        <description>hello<\description>
    </description>
<\description>
```

Supposing that here we use `<description>(.*)<description>(.*)</description>`
It will parse:

```
    <description>
        <description>hello<\description>
    </description>
<\description>
```

So if you want to parse only what is inside the 2nd description you should use `(.*?)` it is called non greedy
Using `<description>(.*)<description>(.*?)</description>` will parse:

```
<description>
    <description>hello<\description> # end of parse
# here <\description> is missing cause (.*?) will look only for the first match
```

So you must use `(.*?)` it will stop parsing right when it found the first end match, but `(.*)` is greedy so it will look for largest match possible

So if you use `<description>(.*)<description>(.*?)</description>` it will be fine, cause it will parse only what is inside the sub description in your case

Comment: This one seemed to select a little too much still. If there were multiple occurrences, it selected everything in between as well up to the last occurrence

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we'd be designing an expression to exclude `<notadescription>`, such as:

```
<description>(?!<notadescription>)[\s\S]*<\/description>
```

which if we would be capturing the description element, we might want a capturing group:

```
(<description>(?!<notadescription>)[\s\S]*<\/description>)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lHw6RQ/1/)

Comment: In notepad++ this one was a bit too greedy selecting from first to the last, but also selecting the ones that didnt match this.